# Restarting a loop with a signal

Tags: ruby, loops, signals

Let's say I have a program with a loop like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts $$

def do_work
   puts Time.now
end

Signal.trap("HUP") do
  do_work
end

loop do
  sleep 60
  do_work
end
```

It "does work" every 60 seconds. Sometimes I don't want to wait the full 60 seconds though, so I trap a `HUP` signal to `do_work` instantly. This works great, except for one thing: I want the 60 second clock to reset after the signal is handled. The way it's setup now, if the sleep is @ 45 seconds and I send the program the `SIGHUP`, it will `do_work` and then 15 seconds later it will `do_work` again.

How can I rework this to function with the above constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I tested my code with the signal INT (triggered by ctrl+C) as I am on Windows, which doesn't have HUP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals leads me to believe that HUP should work fine also, but I can't be 100% sure.

For the example code you listed, you can move `sleep 60` from the loop to inside the `do_work` method:

```
def do_work
  puts Time.now
  sleep 60
end

Signal.trap("HUP") do
  do_work
end

loop do
  do_work
end
```

However, there are probably better ways to encapsulate the logic and make it re-usable. Here is what I came up with:

```
class Worker
  attr_accessor :interval
  attr_reader :times_worked

  def initialize(interval, signal)
    @signal = signal
    @interval = interval
    @times_worked = 0
  end

  def set_task(&block)
    @work_to_do = block
    Signal.trap(signal) { do_work }
    start
  end

  def stop
    @stop = true
  end

  def start
    @stop = false
    loop do
      break if @stop
      do_work
    end
  end

  def do_work
    @work_to_do.call
    @times_worked += 1 # just an example of something you could put here
    sleep @interval
  end
end

worker = Worker.new(5, "HUP")
worker.set_task { puts Time.now }
```

Comment: While it looks like it works it's a terrible solution. `HUP` will interrupt currently running `do_work` in the middle (not necessary in the middle of `sleep`) and start another `do_work`. Besides it can't be interrupted second time while inside `trap` block. And doing anything heavy inside `trap` is a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: I'll admit, I kind of just threw this together, I have actually never used the `Signal` class until now. Perhaps I should have been more frank about that. I will say, I did have fun making this code =)

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
q1, q2 = (0..1).map { Queue.new }

Thread.new do
  loop do
    time, seq = q1.pop
    delta = time - Time.now
    sleep delta if delta > 0
    q2.push seq
  end
end

Signal.trap("HUP") do
  Thread.new do
    q2.push nil
  end
end

seq = 0
q2.push seq
loop do
  # Drop expired sequences
  while (event_seq = q2.pop; event_seq && event_seq != seq)
  end

  # If HUP expire current sequence
  seq += 1 unless event_seq

  # Do work here
  p Time.now

  q1.push [Time.now + 60, seq]
end
```